# Linking my own Git server with my Windows Eclipse IDE

Tags: linux, windows, eclipse, git, ssh

I'm trying since two days to set up a private Git and link it with my Eclipse IDE.

First of all, I have a Raspberry running Rasbian as a server. SSH is working with SSH keys.
I created a new user to store my Git projects on. Git is installed too.

My dev computer is running Windows 10 and Eclipse Neon.1 with the Git plugin installed on. I have MSysGit installed too.

And here I can't link anything to make it working well together.

First, I didn't find how can I tell to EGit to use a SSH key. So I wanted to use the Git GUi provided by MSysGit but I don't know how to link it with my server.

I'm not here to ask you to setting up for me or even tell me how to do it step by step, I'm just looking for a detailled tutorial or video which can helps me with it. Most of tutorial I rode use Linux as dev OS, or link Eclipse directly on GitHub so I didn't find a situation like mine.

Comment: Is this a help: http://monkeyhacks.com/post/raspberry-pi-as-private-git-server ?

Comment: Thanks ! I successfully add a remote as origin with it. But I'm using ssh key to log into my server so when I type "git push origin master" I got an error telling me "Permission denied (publickey)" which is normal but I'm not able to configure git to use a specific ssh key (I generated for the git user especially for git)

Answer (score 0):

First you need git setting done in eclipse that provide GUI for git commands.
Then to link local server, add you local git server URL to your project remote URL. and it should be able to pull & push commit to your server.

This tutorial should be enough for all you need.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html

http://monkeyhacks.com/post/raspberry-pi-as-private-git-server

Comment: Sorry for the copy/paste but I ask you too : I successfully add a remote as origin with it. But I'm using ssh key to log into my server so when I type "git push origin master" I got an error telling me "Permission denied (publickey)" which is normal but I'm not able to configure git to use a specific ssh key (I generated for the git user especially for git)